# How to delete elements from nested array of documents with spring mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I have the following type of document representing projects in Mongo DB :

```js
{
    "_id" : "5f69c22b669f2d3b308ce2e2",
    "actions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "1",
            ...
        }, 
        {
            "_id" :"2",
            ...
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "n",
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

and I'd like to delete specified actions by their actionsIds for the project projectId.

I tried the code below :

```java
mongoOperation.updateMulti(
    Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(projectId)),
    new Update().pull("actions", Query.query(Criteria.where("id").in(actionIds))),
    Project.class
);
```

But it doesn't delete anything.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: Your data uses `_id`, your query uses `id`. Get the query working in mongo shell before trying to use java mappers.

Comment: Thanks for your advice but it seams that "_id" and "id" are synonymous with spring mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out how to do it :

```java
DBObject pullUpdate = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add(
      "id",
      BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("$in", actionIds).get()
).get();
mongoOperation.updateMulti(
      Query.query(Criteria.where("id").is(projectId)),
      new Update().pull("actions", pullUpdate),
      Project.class
);
```